# Electromagnetic tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

How to prove the equality in this?
$$F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\left(\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}-\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}\right)\left(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\right)=2g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\left(\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\right)\left(\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}-\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\right)$$

Comment: Have you tried expanding the second expression?

Comment: I have but I still don't get it.

Comment: What is your field, Professor? Anyway, keep trying. There is no point to the exercise if you don't work it out yourself.

Comment: Do you understand that a contracted index can be relabeled using a different letter?

Comment: @my2cts, I'm a professor in general relativity.

Answer (score 1):

Good news everybody! I solved the problem! The trick was that you had to write it open into four terms and then change the sum indices of two of those terms (one with plus and one with minus in front of the term). So you can change the indices for example in this way: $\alpha \rightarrow \beta, \beta \rightarrow \alpha,\mu \rightarrow \nu, \nu \rightarrow \mu$. Here is the solution:
\begin{eqnarray*}
F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} & = & g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\left(\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}-\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}\right)\left(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\right)\\
 & = & g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}-g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}+g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\beta}A_{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\\
 & = & g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}-g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}+g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\\
 & = & 2g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\beta}\left(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}